# Switching between divs like pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have several div elements with incremental IDs (e.g. div0, div1, div2 (I know this is bad practice - I'm developing a dynamic CSV-to-HTML converter for Outlook calendar exports)) and I'd like to switch between them using jQuery linked to forward/back buttons . What I'm trying to do is as follows (in meaningless pseudo-code):

```
int pos = 0
forward.onclick
    hide ("#div"+pos)
    pos++
    show ("#div"+pos)
back.onclick
    if pos != 0
        hide ("#div"+pos)
        pos--
        show ("#div"+pos)
```

Since I know next to nothing about jQuery, my questions are 1. What would the syntax be for implementing the above example (assuming I'm on the right track), and 2. Is there a way in jQuery to somehow check for an upper boundary so the counter doesn't increase above the number of divs?

Comment: `in meaningless pseudo-code` - what about a check for maximum page? Otherwise, convert that to javascript and you're good to go

Comment: Do you not use React yet?

Comment: That's part of my question - how would I go about checking for an upper bound? I barely know jQuery at all so I have no idea if such a function exists.

Comment: Give all your DIVs the same class. jQuery has methods for getting all the elements with a class, then counting and indexing them. That's how you can tell if you've reached the end.

Comment: @Sam `$('.className').length` will tell you the upper bound of all the DIVs with that class.

Comment: Read Jquery .show(), .hide() and .length it will help

Comment: @Deep `length` is not a function.

Comment: @Barmar thanks, just corrected it

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, that's exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how many divs you have in jQuery, select them and take the length of your selection:

```
$('.div').length
```

You could even just use that selection to cycle through which divs to show:

```
var $divs = $('.div');
var upperLimit = $divs.length - 1;
var index = 0;

// on arrow click
$($divs[index]).hide();
index++ (or index--, depending on the arrow)
$($divs[index]).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

`int` is not a data type in JavaScript. Use `var`. Declaration would be `var pos = Number(0)`.  To prevent exceeding the boundaries of number of divs, declare a variable with the number of divs you have, and inside your hide and show calls, use `pos℅divLength` instead of `pos`. Suppose you have total divs as 4, you will never exceed `div3` this way. It will iterate from `div0` to `div3`. Refer [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp) to learn how to use show and hide methods.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a demo.](http://codepen.io/Chevex/pen/ggGEPN)

```
var index = 0;
$('#div' + index).show();
$('#next').click(function () {
  index++;
  $('#back').prop('disabled', false);
  if (index === fakeData.length - 1) {
    $('#next').prop('disabled', true);
  }
  $('.items').hide();
  $('#div' + index).show();
});
$('#back').click(function () {
  index--;
  $('#next').prop('disabled', false);
  if (index === 0) {
    $('#back').prop('disabled', true);
  }
  $('.items').hide();
  $('#div' + index).show();
});
```

The above code will disable and enable the next and back buttons based on whether you are at the beginning or the end of your list of data. It hides all elements and then shows the specific one that should be shown.